# Extract unique values from named range

Tags: vba, excel

I have created the named range list of worksheets in the `Working` tab for Cell `AD3:AD25` from which I want to pull the Unique Values from Cell `A2` to the last range of Column `A` **from every named range worksheet** and for the same I have created Name Manager as `MySheets` and by using the Named range I want to extract the Unique Values.

<sub>Expected results shown below. Click image for sample workbook on Google Drive:</sub>

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PEasdNSX8TtvYinAwo4PJgFz3JtfvfSO/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do (or why you need to do this in VBA).  Yuu want a unique list of values from column `A` for in each worksheet listed in a named range?  Is that correct?  Why? is this a one time thing?  Is your example representative of your actual worksheet (ir., how many values?)  Is this a one time thing?  Anyhow, you need to post what you have tried so far.  (See "[mcve]" and also "[ask]".)

Comment: The reason is In the original workbook, there are many other worksheets except the named range List worksheets. So i want to extract the unique values only from mysheets as used for named range. I am fine if the formula can do so. Either formula or VBA will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the folliwing:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Working")

    Dim currCell As Range
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each currCell In ws.Range("MySheets")

        Dim currSht As Worksheet

        On Error Resume Next

        Set currSht = wb.Worksheets(currCell.Value)

        With currSht

            Dim loopRange As Range
            Set loopRange = .Range("A2:A" & GetLastRow(currSht))

            Dim loopValue As Range

            For Each loopValue In loopRange

                If Not dict.exists(loopValue.Value) Then
                    dict.Add loopValue.Value, loopValue.Value
                End If

            Next loopValue

        End With

        On Error GoTo 0

    Next currCell

    ws.Range("AE2").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys)

End Sub
Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal sht As Worksheet) As Long

With sht

    GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End With

End Function
```

Comment: Awesome. Perfectly worked. Thanks a ton QHarr. I do appreciate your precious contribution. Many thanks.

Comment: could you take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031501/vba-code-to-extract-unique-list-from-table?noredirect=1#comment106169457_60031501 ?